# If $f$ is Schwartz, does there exist a positive Schwartz function $g$ such that $|f(x)| \leq g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is a Schwartz function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that takes positive and negative values. Does there exist a Schwartz function $g$ such that $|f(x)| \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$? Is there an explicit construction of such a $g$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For a construction see the note by Garrett
http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/weil_schwartz_envelope.pdf